# Existence of liquid phase of metal below triple point pressure in vacuum chamber

Tags: thermodynamics, vacuum, phase-transition, evaporation, phase-diagram

As part of my work, I perform localized heating of metals using a CW laser, upto and past the melting point, inside a vacuum chamber with typical ambient pressures of $\sim 10^{-9}\,$mbar. However, I have noticed that for many elements (ie Silicon and Titanium), I can still readily obtain a liquid phase through heating, despite being at pressures lower than the triple point, which would mean that a liquid phase should not form.

Have I misinterpreted the meaning of the triple point with relation to vacuum systems? Has the existence of liquid metals in a vacuum environments below their triple points been studied before?

Comment: Yes, liquid metals in vacuum is quite common. Your hot molten pool is not in thermodynamic equilibrium with the cold chamber walls. The triple point has no bearing on the melt which is evaporating metal just fine.

Comment: @JonCuster So you are saying that because this system is in not in an equilibrium state, the ambient vapor pressure within in the region of the melt pool maybe much higher than what my pressure gauge would read for the ambient vacuum pressure?

Comment: Absolutely, and any vapor is coating out on the wall. Also understand that thermodynamics says nothing about how fast you get to equilibrium- that is kinetics. All the material knows is you’ve pumped in enough energy in a volume to convert it to liquid, and some surface atoms can decide to fly away, never to return (most likely). At your pressure, the mean free path of an atom is much larger than your chamber.

Comment: Ok so using the triple point for a system like this, that is not in thermodynamic equilibrium is not valid? I still think that the ambient pressure plays a role since some materials in vacuum sublimate significantly in vacuum, far before their melting point is reached; which would indicate that the 'boiling point' has moved below the melting point, the movement of which is characterized by the vapor pressure. Wouldn't then this mean that some materials will melt then evaporate when heated in vacuum, whereas others would simply sublimate?